# PHP getopt() suddenly not working

Tags: php, bash, command-line-arguments

I have a daily cron job which runs a PHP script on my hosted webserver:

Cron job command: (xxxxxxxx is my obscured web host account name)

```
/usr/bin/php /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/test.php -t 123qwe
```

test.php partial code:

```
// Get command line argument 't'.
$accesstoken = getopt("t:");
// If the passed token does not match, exit script.
if($accesstoken["t"] != '123qwe') exit();
// Run rest of script...
```

The above code has worked for two years solid, every day no problems, until Jan 3rd this year.

If I var_dump($accesstoken) I get 'bool(false)'.

I have no idea why this isn't working. I've tried using argv but I've proved that STDIN is not defined:

```
if (defined('STDIN')) { echo("STDIN defined"); $type = $argv[1]; }
else { echo("STDIN NOT defined"); }
```

... echos 'STDIN NOT defined'.

Does anyone know of any recent changes to Apache / PHP that could be causing this? Or is there a PHP flag maybe that is suppressing getopt() from working?

Any help on this would be apprecieated :)

Comment: Check your PHP version...

Comment: Hi, firstly, see if you can run this manually from your command line and see whether it behaves as you expect. Secondly, see if you can log the output of php_sapi_name() to a tmp file i.e. file_put_contents('./tmp.txt',php_sapi_name()); you may need to create the file first and set it's write permission. Also, what is the contents of $argv?

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.3.29

Comment: php_sapi_name() returns cgi-fcgi.

Comment: argv doesn't work because STDIN is not defined. If I change the cron command line to /usr/bin/php /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/test.php testarg, and use var_dump($argv) in my script, that echos 'NULL'.

Comment: And I cannot run this manually from the command line I dont have  SSH Access at the moment.

Comment: SSH now enabled. I ran '/usr/bin/php /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/test.php testarg' and still got a NULL value for var_dump($argv) returned on the shell.